# Android FragmentActivity inside Tabhost?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, fragment

I'm trying to implement an app with the following specs:

A tabhost inside a main fragmentActivity.
In each of those tabs, there is a fragment.

In tab B, I have a ListFragment. I want to be able to click on a list element and have a new fragment open in the same tab OVER the list. But I do not want this fragment to take over the entire screen; I still want to be able to switch tabs with the new fragment open. I also want to be able to close the new fragment and see the list again.

How should I go about implementing this? I tried replacing the fragment of tab B with a fragmentActivity so I could handle the transition between the fragments, but the tabhost complained.

Is there some way to launch another fragment (that takes over the current fragment's location in the activity) from tab B? I want to be able to close the new fragment and go back to the list of tab B.

Update: I figured it out! There's something called fragment backstacks.

Comment: would a dialogFragment work for your  purposes? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I have a fragment class that contains a ViewPagerAdapter that I want to launch upon item click, so the DialogFragment is not complex enough for me.

Comment: Cool! Do future readers a favor and answer your own question :)

Comment: Why not use the ActionBar's tabs? They support fragments much better and implement the UI pattern of the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: use fragment backstacks! you can do it from within the fragment you want to replace!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html